# Unable to pass payload when they are like html elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've written a script in python using post request to fetch certain content from a webpage but I can hardly understand how to pass payload parameter with the request. So far I knew they always appear as dictionary but in this case the scenario is totally different.

How to pass payload in such cases:

```
<ob_post eventname="getFacilityProfile"><param name="CSRFCheck"><![CDATA[4.6433849073184]]></param></ob_post>
```

As it may look weird, I'm including the image of it for your consideration.

[image]

The code I'm currently using is

```py
params = {
'facId': 'XmkBHsU855E=',
'FAC_TYPE': 'NH'
}

payload = {
    """<ob_post eventname="getServices"><param name="CSRFCheck"><![CDATA[0.2879677108264]]></param></ob_post>"""
}

with requests.session() as s:
    req = s.get(profile_link,params=params)
    resp = s.post(req.url,data=payload)
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code that you are using to send your POST request.

Comment: I don't understand how to. However, as you insist, [check it out](https://pastebin.com/HG4NDT7A) @Conspicuous Compiler.

Comment: I edited the code you linked into your question for you.  In the future, you can click the 'edit' button under your question and add requested information that way.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with the code you've provided, there's really not enough information to help you.  The service you're accessing clearly takes parameters both in the query parameters and in the POST body.  You demonstrate in your code how to send both.  However, you don't state the specific parameter you need to pass nor provide documentation of the service.  We need more information if you want help.  Linking to documentation of the API in question would be a good step forward.